# Unprintable characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I want to test if a certain BLOB starts with character 255 (`\xff`). Is there a way to encode this character in a literal string?

[Table 9.1. Special Character Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences) gives certain special characters but not a way to encode arbitrary characters.

Failing a way to encode characters, is there a different workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hexadecimal literal, e.g. X'FF'.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Comment: Specifically, try something like `select * from foo where text like CONCAT('%', 0xxff, '%');`